# display:inline-table not working for small content width

Tags: css

I'm writing CSS for a web application where users can upload photos for others to see. All photos appear as polaroids. I.e white padding around them, with extended padding at the bottom. The design is fully responsive.

And if a user includes a caption, the text appears within the polaroid, at the bottom of the photo. The whitespace in the bottom extends to accommodate the length of the text. This is all achieved via CSS.

**The problem:** when photo widths are small (i.e. for thumbnails), the polaroid effect starts breaking down and text captions start overflowing. Can you help me maintain my styling's integrity for small image sizes? Would love an illustrative example, preferably with well-support CSS 2.1 attributes since a substantial number of users I have to cater are Opera Mini browsers with thin CSS3 or JS support.

---

**Two examples of correct layout:**

1) Thumbnail:

[image]

2) Big image:

[image]

---

**Two examples of incorrect layout:**

1) Thumbnail of the big image above:

[image]

2) Another thumbnail:

[image]

And note that these same thumbs display correctly without a caption, e.g.:

[image]

---

And finally, here's my CSS:

```
 .mbs{
    margin-bottom:0.5em;
    }

 .bw {
    word-wrap:break-word;
    }

 .polaroid{
    text-align:center;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    }

 .sh-l{
   -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 2px 2px #90C0B0; 
   -moz-box-shadow: -2px 2px 2px #90C0B0;
   box-shadow: -2px 2px 2px #90C0B0;
    }

 .inner-img{
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   border-radius: 12px;
    }

 .img-caption{
   display: table-caption;
   caption-side: bottom;
   width:100%;
    }

 .cgy{
   color:grey;
   text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
   margin-bottom:0.5em;
    }
```

And here's the HTML:

```
    <div class="mbs polaroid sh-l" style="padding:5px">
       <div style="display: inline-table;">
       <img src="{{ img_url }}" height="38" class="mbs inner-img" style="border-radius:4px;margin-bottom: 8px;" alt="photo">
       {% if img_caption %}<div class="cgy bw img-caption"><bdi>{{ img_caption }}</bdi></div>{% endif %}
       </div>
    </div>
```

Ignore `{{` and `{%`, that's just Django syntax. This code has served me well, so I don't want to make too many changes, unless really warranted.

Comment: You have `word-wrap: break-word`. What else were you expecting?

Comment: @jhpratt: what do you mean?

Comment: You're explicitly telling the browser to only break for a new line on word boundaries.

Comment: Oh, you mean I had to try `word-break: break-all;`, I think you're right, hold on!

Comment: @jhpratt: worked mate. If you write that as an answer, I'll mark it accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `word-wrap: break-word`, which tells the browser to only break for new lines on word boundaries. What you're looking for is `word-break: break-all`, which allows individual words to be split where necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try `word:break: break-all` instead of `word-wrap:break-word;` 
One breaks the string at a word level while the other breaks the string at the letter level, which is what you want. This is a very common mistake devs make in CSS. Honestly at times I still make the same mistake :)